# Using a central RabbitMQ Cluster with local instances federated for store and forward

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

We're experimenting with RabbitMQ and MassTransit. We currently have 3 rabbit instances set up on load balanced servers. We also have two more in a cluster over a VPN. What I was hoping to set up was local rabbit instances on each of the application hosts so that we could have local store and forward. Then these queues in the central cluster could be forwarded on to the offsite cluster.

I tried to set up federation on the local instance to the central cluster, then federation from the remote cluster to the central cluster. The exchanges appear on each one, however there are no bindings so when I publish from MassTransit it doesn't move the messages to any queues.

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding a concept somewhere. Hopefully this all makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the default configuration for the federation upstream is to limit the hops to 1. So in the start configuration the messages hopped to the central cluster and were dropped. I raised the hops to two and now the bindings are shared from one host, to the cluster and down to the other host.